# How to append new item to existing redis key with exchange.redis

Tags: c#, arrays, json, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have json array stored in Redis Database.
Now when I want to add new item to database I do it with the following way:

```
  var lJson = Database.StringGet("myKey");
                if (dictJson.HasValue)
                {
                    var currentObjects = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(lJson );
                    currentObjects.Add(newObject);
                    string newJsonText= JsonConvert.SerializeObject(currentGameTickets);
                    Database.StringSet("myKey", newJsonText);
                 }    
        }
```

but when there is heavy load to this function I can see that Garbage Collector actively working, I assume that if currentObjects is big array Database.StringSet function may take a long time.
So I would like to just append my newObject to existing array.

Answer (score 0):

If you can migrate your data to another data type you can try something like this:

Use [List](https://redis.io/topics/data-types#lists) data type as storage for your objects. Using [RPUSH](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) you can append a new item to the list.

```
RPUSH myKey '{"key":"value"}'
```

Use [RedisJSON](https://redis.io/commands/rpush) module.

```
JSON.SET myKey . []
JSON.ARRAPPEND myKey . '{"key":"value"}'
```